# User agent check for Windows device

Tags: windows, user-agent, apex-code, apex

I'm using something similar to the following code snippet in my Apex controller to check if someone is accessing my website from an iPhone or Android phone.

```
userAgent.contains('iPhone') || ( userAgent.contains('Android') && userAgent.contains('Mobile'));
```

Can I use something similar to check if someone is using a Windows device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the version of [categorizr](http://www.brettjankord.com/2012/01/16/categorizr-a-modern-device-detection-script/) I have on hand, the following detects windows mobile:

```
userAgent.contains('Windows.NT.5')
```

I'm not sure if  a more recent list needs applying

Comment: Cheers Scott, I'm using IEMobile at the moment and it's working as well.